# How to configure Git SSH for multiple users in the same computer

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

HTTP credentials (windows machine) create a permanent identity from this machine for a single user. When commits are made if there isn't a credential Git prompt their username & password login interface and create a reference for this machine for the single user that just log in.

This is problematic in two kind of situations:

1. Developers that share a machine
2. Developer that has more than one project and access to them from his/her different accounts

Git is a software tools commonly used by programmers, we are a team of 16 developers from a tiny startup and some of us are sharing their machine to work with who came after in the next turn.

Nowadays we need a practical configuration of Git tool that let us answer the problem of user coexistence to develop our software replacing the bad practice implemented by need.

Git allow multiple user configuration for SSH pull/push/etc but we can't find an example or documentation that works.

##### What we do - the bad practice:

This is **one machine** (pc computer - windows 10) that is **used by 4 user (tom, bob, anna & cindy)** , each of them are working in different github repos.

Everyday who come first deletes all the credentials and ssh-keygen, set their own and work in their project. And each user do the same.

##### What configuration we try:

We try to ssh-keygen `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "tom/bob/anna/cindy@email.com"`, added to ssh agent, and we set in our repos. This not work, we get a "git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)".

We try `credential` configs like username, email --global, and git configs. Nothing works. `-vT` connects us with our correct user. crendetial.helper

We have our tom.pub, bob.pub, anna.pub & cindy.pub, even a id_rsa.pub, each of us with their own key in their own repo.

Https credentials, config --local/--global

### This is our main question:

**How can be Git be configured that a single machine relate multiple SSH keys with multiple user accounts, where each user be related with their own account?**

Comment: Yuck. Options: (1) spend about US$150 on four raspberry pi machines and give everyone their own machine; (2) install Linux and give everyone their own account (free).

Comment: Even with Windows you should be able to have separate user accounts.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do this is to create a separate user account for each user and then let them configure it appropriately.  Git, like OpenSSH and virtually every other program originally written for Unix machines, is designed on the principle that each user has a separate account and that their personal configuration is stored under their home directory.

If you share a user account, you will also inevitably have problems with editor configuration, `.gitconfig`, shell configuration, and various other tooling, so doing so is not recommended.

Answer (score 2):

## Multiple GitHub accounts on the same machine (ssh config)

### 3 Steps

1. rsa key   (one per user)
2. Global `config` file in `~/.ssh/`
3. Remote url

##### 1. rsa key   (one per user)

```
# Generating a SSH key
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "any@email.com" -f "anyName"

# enable ssh-agent
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"

# Register with ssh-agent the new SSH Keys
ssh-add ~/.ssh/anyName

# Adding SSH key to GitHub -> Settings -> SSH and GPG keys (copy/paste)
# key inside this [file].pub filename
# 'cat' command will prompt it out to copy/paste
cat anyName.pub
```

##### 2. Global `config` file in `~/.ssh/`

It's possible to have several [aliases] for the same hostname and create a reference to diferents users with it own authorization. We can configure ssh to use a specific encryption key depending on the host (Host alias).

Create a `config` file in `~/.ssh/` :

```
# Default GitHub
Host [alias1]
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/alias1

# Professional github alias
Host [alias2]
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/alias2
```

##### 3. Remote url

There is two suggested ways to modify the "remote" reference, to choose one or the other relies on needs.

1. git commmand 
   This option is enough to pull and push.

```
git remote add origin git@[alias]:[git-user]/[repo].git
```

2. Editing the local `config` file within the local repo (in `./project-name/.git/config`) 
   If more complex configs are required.

A `./project-name/.git/config` will be more or less like this example:

```
[core]
    [...]
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:user2/web-project.git
    [...]
```

This is the target line: (this line is the remote)

```
url = git@github.com:[git-user]/[repo].git
```

**It must be changed by the `Host alias` from our `config` files like this:**

```
url = git@[alias]:[git-user]/[repo].git
```

Comment: This is all very interesting but it is _not programming_. This whole discussion needs to be on superuser or similar.